# Python lists: update list indices with a new element

Tags: python, list

I've experience in R and I'm currently moving to Python, I ran into this weird issue.
I am trying to update a list index with an element.
Basically, I have this list `updated_assignements`, which I want to update element in index 0 and element in index 1 with a specific new element I calculated.
What I tried:

```
updated_assignemnts[0:2] = [[next,intersect]]
# I am putting in remarks the already pre-calculated values of the new element
# next = 28 (int)
# intersent = {'weightlifting'} (set)
```

What I discovered after this assignment is that updated_assignemnts had not changed at the required index.
Any ideas why ?

Comment: Remove the extra set of `[` and `]`

Comment: If you don't understand, Bhargav means that use `updated_assignemnts[0:2] = [next,intersect]` instead.

Comment: `updated_assignemnts[0:2]`  does change your list, it replaces two elements with one

Answer (score 2):

Python will put as many elements in the range as you provide:

```
x=[3,4,5,6]
x[0:2] = [[10,11]]  # providing one element, a list: [10,11]
x                   # [[10, 11], 5, 6]

x=[3,4,5,6]
x[0:2] = [10,11]    # providing two elements: 10 and 11.
x                   # [10, 11, 5, 6]

x=[3,4,5,6]
x[0:2] = range(5)   # providing 5 elements.
x                   # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: so in my case I need to multiply [next,intersect] by 2. In the genric case how do I create a sublist of length n with repeating elements [next,intersect]  ?